# How to get size of the blue text selection?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to know if it's possible to get the size (the width and height) of the blue box that appears when you select a text.
[image: Get selection text width height and size]

Comment: Nothing yet. I have absolutely no clue of how to do it. I'm still a beginner in programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("area").addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  var bcr = getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
  document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "W: "+ bcr.width +' H:'+ bcr.height;
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="area">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat consectetur incidunt vel praesentium cum blanditiis tempora doloribus culpa odit! Labore at cum ad, voluptas nobis nam iste non omnis vitae?
</div>
<b id="info"></b>
```

So after you got the selection's range `.getBoundingClientRect()` into a `bcr` variable you can retrieve from now on any value that this method provides such as

**width, height, top, left, right, bottom**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: Thanks for your reply Roko, but i was hoping i could get the selection  dimensions as i selected the text. Example, i select the word "text" and it gives me the size of the selection box for that text, but it should work for every text that i select. If there's a way to put the selected text into a span than it would work.

Comment: @HebertAG OK edited my answer, in any way use `.getBoundingClientRect()` :)

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for. Thanks! Do you know if there's a way i could also get the selection box position (x and y)? This is just out of curiosity, what i wanted was just the dimensions.

Comment: @HebertAG yes, if you followed my previous answer I have shown you how to do that too. And that's using `bcr.left` and `bcr.top`. please, always try to give a look at the useful MDN pages for methods that you don't know what they actually do: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: Thanks. I'll definitely do that.